# Multiple slick slider on page ... unwanted synchron sliding

Tags: javascript, slider, slick.js

- Page with multiple sliders based on slick-slider.
- Some use custom paging.
- All sliders with custom paging move synchronously, but they shouldn't.

I have a page with multiple sliders based on slick-slider.
Here is a link http://www.kryolan.einfach-beginnen.de/home.html
Some of these slider use a custom paging to show something like 1/4 or 2/4 and custom prev next button.
Works great, but all sliders with the custom paging on this page 
move synchronously. And I can't find out why.
I don't want them to to move synchronously.
All other sliders are fine.

I also tried to call them "really separate" by calling them separate with their ID. But this changed nothing.

My guess is it's something with the paging, but I can't find out why and how.

Any ideas?

My code:

```
   $('.trendlooks .product-slider').each(function(){          
      var $status = $(this).closest('.pagingInfo span');
      var $slickElement = $(this);

      $slickElement.on('init reInit afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
            //currentSlide is undefined on init -- set it to 0 in this case (currentSlide is 0 based)
            var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
            $status.text(i + '/' + slick.slideCount);
      });

      $slickElement.slick({
          dots: true,
          pauseOnDotsHover: true,
          infinite: true,
          speed: 500,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          autoplay: false,
          arrows:false
        });

      $slickElement.parent().find('.pagingInfo .next-slide').click(function(){
            $slickElement.slick('slickNext');
            console.log($slickElement.attr('id'));
        });
      $slickElement.parent().find('.pagingInfo .prev-slide').click(function(){
            $slickElement.slick('slickPrev');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just checked your site, and there are two problems causing this, and it's not related to the code that you pasted here.

That code is actually doing nothing, because the `$status` variable is uninitialized in that closure when the afterChange event is fired, you should use this code instead to update the text of that span:

`$('.pagingInfo span', slick.$slider.parent()).text(i + '/' + slick.slideCount)`

The problem causes the "fake updates" is firstly at `main.js` line 594:

`var $status = $('.pagingInfo span');`

After this call, the `$status` variable holds ALL of the `.pagingInfo` spans, not the only one thats inside `.shopteaser-slider`.

At line 613 and 616 you add a click listener again to ALL next and prev buttons (not just the shopteaser-slider ones) to trigger an event on shopteaser-slider, and after that, the callback at line 597 sets the `$status` (which holds all of your `.pagingInfo span`) text to shopteaser-slider currentSlide value.

This is why you see that everything is synced.

Solution:

Be more specific at line 594: `$('.pagingInfo span', $('.shopteaser-slider').parent())` or something.

And at lines 613 and 616: Instead `$('.next-slide').click` be more specific: `$('.next-slide', $('.shopteaser-slider').parent())` or something more specific.

Or just use ID-s.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, this works. Great.
You are my hero. :)

Thanks a lot.